# Git bash command prompt hanging when running dvc push to DAGsHub

Tags: dvc

I'm having problems pushing files with DVC to DAGsHub.

Workflow:

- I used my email to signup to DAGsHub.
- I created a repo and clone it to my computer.
- I added files to the repo and track them using DVC and Git to track the pointer files.
- Running DVC push -r origin, it asks me for my password. When I enter the password and hit enter - nothing happens.

It sits and waits, barring me from even canceling the operation with Ctrl+C.
I'm forced to manually close the terminal, open a new one, ending the "Python" process in task manager and delete the lock file in .dvc/tmp/lock.

Comment: Are you doing this with git bash on windows?

Comment: Yes, is it a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Do not use `ask_password`.
Instead, save your token in the local config by running once:

```
dvc remote modify origin --local --unset ask_password
dvc remote modify origin --local password <--access token-->
```

`dvc push -r origin` should work then.

**Long answer**

[Git Bash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Git%20Bash%3F,operating%20system%20through%20written%20commands.) is not running the regular Windows command prompt but an emulated Unix-style bash prompt. From the information in your question, I cannot know for sure, but this is probably causing the `msvcrt` package used by DVC to prompt the password on windows machines to fail/hang.

There are potentially 3 ways to deal with the issue:

1. Run `dvc pull` from the regular Windows cmd prompt.
2. Find a way to make Git Bash wrap Python calls with `winpty` - I am not 100% positive about how to do this, but not using `winpty` seems to be the reason `msvcrt` fails at prompting for your password.
3. The simplest solution - Do not use `ask_password`.
   Instead, save your token in the local config by running once:

   ```
   dvc remote modify origin --local --unset ask_password
   dvc remote modify origin --local password <--access token-->
   ```

   You can get your access token by clicking on the question mark beside the DVC
   remote of your DAGsHub repository, then click on "Reveal my token".